# download XML file from server

Tags: iphone

**hi guys,i parse my file xml from my server**

```
NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [Conn.webData mutableBytes] length:[Conn.webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSLog(theXML);
    [theXML release];
```

**but now i want download this file in my iPhone,it possible to do this?**

**i see this exemple but i not undersund :**

```
NSString *path=[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"file.txt"];

// save the people array
BOOL saved=[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:people toFile:path];
if(saved){
    //NSLog(@"saved");
}else{
    //NSLog(@"Not saved");
};

// reload array
people=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
if(newArray==nil)
{
    // create new array
    people=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}else{
    // retener los datos
    [perople retain];
};
```

Comment: Try to be more specific for what you want to do.

Comment: i want download file.xml from server and saved in my iphone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308159/download-a-file-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: options: error:] and [data writeToFile: options:1 error:]; for doing this.

Comment: i want download file not parsing

Comment: There is no parser, dataWithContentOfUrl download file from url into NSData and writeToFile save it into your iPod and no matter what the file is for the link - I downloaded small images this way, not only xml. NSString have metod writeToFile too

Comment: what u mean with option can u explain me please

Comment: This is read-write files different options, better read more about them in the Xcode Help. There are similar methods without options like writeToFile:atomically:

Comment: i try this  
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1/webservice2/theflah.xml"]]; 
 
 [data writeToFile:@"/Users/mediatun1/Desktop/chikos" atomically:YES];

Comment: but i not see theflah.xml in folder chikos

Comment: my question haw i can create theflah.xml in my folder chikos

Comment: I dont know, how can you write file in custom plase in iphone filesystem and not sure that it possible. I'm not sure iphone FS has folder /Users/mediatun1/Desktop too.